# I won't able to understand how the second step comes from first

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In algebra book vol-1 by T K Manicavachagom pillay i won't found how second step arrive, i do simplification and found it is different from what is in book . i attach the image of that page can anyone explain how it arrive please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line, expanded, the terms not involving $x$ add up to $(-7/x^2)(-x^2)+(7/x)(-x)+-2(-1)=7/2-7+2=-3/2.$

In the second line there is one such term :   $(7/2x^2)(3x^2)=21/2.$

So there is an error in the text. Probably a typo.

Comment: Yeah I too found exactly the same answer you give ...I too think there is error in text but I'm not sure of that

Comment: I believe in you thanks